# MsChart image is not displaying sometime on jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mschart

I had a chart on a webpage dashborad.aspx. I have added MapAreaAttribute to display chart details on click event of the bar of chart. Code:

```
   foreach (Series series in SalesChart.Series)
    {
        for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < series.Points.Count; pointIndex++)
        {
            string toolTip = "";
            string url = "DetailedSalesChart.aspx?region=" + series.Points[pointIndex].AxisLabel + "&param=" + series.Name;

            toolTip = "<IMG SRC=RegionChart.aspx?region=" + series.Points[pointIndex].AxisLabel + "&param=" + series.Name + ">";

            series.Points[pointIndex].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"DisplayTooltip('" + toolTip + "');\" onmouseout=\"DisplayTooltip('');\"" + " onclick=\"javascript:OpenPopUp('" + url + "');\"";
        }
    }
```

OpenPopUp() is a javascript method to open page in JQuery dialog

```
 <script>
    function OpenPopUp(url) {

        $('#dialog').load(url, function () {
            $(this).dialog({
                modal: true,
                dialogClass:'popupModal',
                height: 400,
                width:520
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

When chart is loading first time in jquery dialog it load properly but when I click one of the bar to show another details of the chart and coming back on the previous bar to see chart again, it's gone and image is disappeared!!! only a cross red mark no image sign is there.

The config for chart handler is here:
           add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=360;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the issue:
Chart was keeping the image in memory even if in appsetting it was mentioned to keep in file mode.

What I did is, before binding data to the chart I have changed a property of the chart. here is that :

```
   ChartDetails.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;
```

and this has resolved my problem.

Hope this will help anybody in future. :)